# Is 1/2" flexible gas pipe adequate for a 22000 BTU clothes dryer?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, natural-gas

I have 1” black iron pipe running just shy of 40’ to a manifold. The manifold then has one run of csst coming off it to my furnace. I then have 4 more ports I can run off for new appliances as I convert them to gas. My electric dryer just went up I would like to replace it with gas. The run would be about 30’. Is 1/2” csst big enough for that run the dryer is about 22000 btu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I concur, 1/2 inch gas pipe is adequate for the dryer. The only thing I would like to add Is, did the gas company run a 2 psi meter to your home? 
 an easy way to tell is if there is a gas regulator at each appliance. This is a pretty common practice in the state I live in. If it is a 2lbs system, you'll need to have a regulator added to the new appliance. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Wow in the 5 states I have lived in 3/4 psi has been the limit for residential. When my dad was alive we had a gas kiln for drying wood and that was 2 psi but the gas company removed that regulator and put in a standard one some years later for safety reasons. Probably because it had not been used once the exotic woods were all used.